# Move Data from Alternate Rows, and more

Tags: excel, vba

I need to move data from alternate rows (Right Eye): Approx. 11,000 more rows to go.

Step 1:

- Starting with Row 1000
- Move Data From COL A to COL E
- Move Data From COL B to COL F
- Move Data From COL C to COL G
- Move Data From COL D to COL H

Step 2:

- Move this Data in Row 1000 (up) to Row (1000-1)

Manually copying and pasting is taking me ages. Will be much obliged for your help.  Please let  me know if you will need additional information.

This is my first ever post on this board.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Which programming language do you use?

Comment: Hi Nico, So far, "Copy and Paste". I have no knowledge of compiling macros to speed up the process. I will some help with the syntax to get started. TIA, SS

Comment: Is this in Excel? If each line only has those 4 columns, this should be easy. You can export to text, open in Notepad++, replace newlines, import back to Excel: https://superuser.com/questions/604382/remove-every-second-carriage-return-starting-from-line-two

Comment: For Excel support, ask on https://superuser.com

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. What do you mean by "macros"? Usually, they don't need to be compiled. Also, StackOverflow won't write such code for you if you haven't shared any attempt

Comment: @MoveIOPdata Just use the macro recorder and do it manually once. For the others just run the recorded macro then.

Comment: After you move the data from 1000 to 1000-1, what do you do? if you do the same again you will overwrite the data written previously

Comment: Hello, Thanks to all of you for responding. My post wasn't clear. My apologies.

Comment: If you still need help, please clarify your problem by editing your post